# Python - variable changes its value with no obvious reason in a recursive function

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, recursion

I face a strange behaviour - variable changes its value with no obvious reason. Please help me to understand what/why this happens and how to avoid it. Details are given below as inline comments. Print statements are added to the code for convenience.

The idea is to flatten a JSON file by multiplying the higher order data as shown below.

Great many thanks in advance.

**The expected output is:**

```
[{'records': '563'},
{'records': '563', 'id': '1111111', 'title': 'alignable', 'status': 'Completed'},
{'records': '563', 'id': '2222222', 'title': ' no links', 'status': 'something'}]
```

**My Code**

```
test_json = {"records": "563",
             "campaign": [{"id": "1111111", "title": "alignable", "status": "Completed"},
                         {"id": "2222222", "title": " no links", "status": "something"}]
             }


def data_multiplication(initial_nested_data):
    out = [{}]

    def data_multiplication_(nested_data):
        if isinstance(nested_data, list) and len(nested_data) > 0:
            base_dic = out[-1]  # with the current example, this line should ( and is ) executed once only.
            # The main question is how it happens that base_dic changes from [{'records': '563'}]
            for x in nested_data:
                print(f'The base_dictionary before the desired append is: {base_dic}')
                # Works like a breeze when I append the out list with a static dic as below.
                out.append({1: 'This here should be the basic dictionary'})  # Comment this line to switch
                # Starts behaving abnormally if I append the out list as below. 
                # out.append(base_dic)  # Uncomment this line to switch
                print(f'The base_dictionary after the desired append is: {base_dic}')
                data_multiplication_(x)

        elif isinstance(nested_data, dict) or len(nested_data) == 0:
            for x in nested_data:
                if (isinstance(nested_data[x], list) or isinstance(nested_data[x], dict)) and len(nested_data[x]) > 0:
                    data_multiplication_(nested_data[x])
                else:
                    out[-1][x] = nested_data[x]

    data_multiplication_(initial_nested_data)

    return out


if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = data_multiplication(test_json)
```

Comment: Whats the actual output of the program? And what variable is changing?

Comment: `append` doesn't make a copy. Python doesn't implicitly copy objects everywhere like what you'd see in C++.

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. (The minimal part)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be making the problem harder than necessary or there's more to it that your not explaining.  Given your sample input and output, this should work:

```
test_json = {
    "records": "563",
    "campaign": [
        {"id": "1111111", "title": "alignable", "status": "Completed"},
        {"id": "2222222", "title": " no links", "status": "something"}
    ]
}

def data_multiplication(initial_nested_data):
    out = [{}]

    def data_multiplication_recursive(nested_data):

        if isinstance(nested_data, dict):
            for key, value in nested_data.items():
                if isinstance(value, list):
                    data_multiplication_recursive(value)
                else:
                    out[0][key] = value

        elif isinstance(nested_data, list):
            base_dic = out[0]

            for dictionary in nested_data:
                out.append({**base_dic, **dictionary})

    data_multiplication_recursive(initial_nested_data)

    return out

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = data_multiplication(test_json)
    print(result)
```

OUTPUT

```
[
    {'records': '563'},
    {'records': '563', 'id': '1111111', 'title': 'alignable', 'status': 'Completed'},
    {'records': '563', 'id': '2222222', 'title': ' no links', 'status': 'something'}
]
```

Comment: You rock, thank you! It worked when I replaced out.append(base_dic) with out.append({**base_dic}). I wish I knew why... :-) Also I'm making it a bit harder, because I would like it to be relatively universal ( deeper json )

Comment: @AsenGeorgiev, for just a single dictionary, instead of `out.append({**base_dic})` you can simply do `out.append(dict(base_dic))` to force a copy.